# What function should i overload to customize the print output?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a subclass from numpy.ndarray that modify the get-item-by-index behaviour. However, I want to retain the original ndarray output format when someone do print on my subclass. I tried overriding the __iter__ function but doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to have print outputing numbers in the underlying array order given that __getitem__ is overloaded?

```
import numpy as np

class imarray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, d, f):
        nd = np.asarray(d)
        return super(imarray, cls).__new__(cls,(nd.size,), dtype=nd.dtype, buffer=nd).view(imarray)
    def __init__(self, d, f):
        self.f = f
    def __array_finalize__(self, o):
        pass
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return super(imarray, self).__getitem__(self.f(i))
    def __setitem__(self, i, y):
        return super(imarray, self).__setitem__(self.f(i), y)
    def __iter__(self):
        return super(imarray, self).__iter__

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = imarray([1., 2., 3.1415], lambda i:i+1)
    print a[0] # print .2
    a[-1] =.4
    print a[-1] # print .4
    print a # print [ 2. 3.1415 0.4 ] but want [ 0.4 2. 3.1415 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Print returns the objects `__str__` method.

So you need to ovveride `__str__`.

```
>>> class ex():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.val = value
    def __str__(self):
        return self.val * 2


>>> a = ex('A')
>>> print a
AA
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends.

If you print an object, `print` will call it's `__str__` method.

However, if you print a `list` (or `set` or `dict`), `print` will call the list's `__str__` method, which in turn will call the items' **`__repr__`** method. It is weird, but quite easily observable:

```
>>> class B():
...     def __repr__(self): return '__repr__'
...     def __str__(self): return '__str__'
...
>>> print B()
__str__
>>> print [B()]
[__repr__]
>>> print set([B()])
set([__repr__])
>>> print {B(): B()}
{__repr__: __repr__}
```

Comment: ,@InbarRose: \__str__ and \__repr__ doesn't take index as argument. So I don't know how to modify the behaviour of print. Eg. I assume that print loop through elements in the array from 0 to N. In the example above, I need it to display elements as if looping from -1 to N-1. So I don't see how \__str__ and \__repr__ can solve this problem. Perhaps I misunderstand something?